# My ng-model didn't update my $scope value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I am trying to make an input field for numbers that would update my table automatically using `ng-model`.

Here is my controller:

```
carApp.controller("CarsByRatingCtrl", function($scope, getAllCars){
    getAllCars.get().success(function(data){
        $scope.carList = data;
        $scope.minReviewNum = 0;

        if ($scope.minReviewNum > 0){
            console.log("passed!")
            for(var i=0;i<$scope.carList.length;i++){
                if ($scope.carList[i]["review"]<$scope.minReviewNum){
                    $scope.carList.splice(i, 1);
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the part if my input field:

```
<input type="number" min="0" step="10" value="0" name="num" ng-model="minReviewNum"></input>
```

But if I run my app it would neither update my table as I change numbers nor return to the console "passed!" message.

What have I done wrong and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use AngularJS filter for this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Otherwise you need to use $scope.$apply http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in your view and you have specified the controller:

```
ng-controller="CarsByRatingCtrl"
```

You would need to use a watch on the scope variable to run updates automatically on that variable.

```
$scope.$watch('minReviewNum', function() { //... });
```

Answer (score -1):

use this :

```
<input type="number" min="0" step="10" value="0" name="num" ng-model="minReviewNum" ng-change="update()"></input>
```

and as a controller use this:

```
carApp.controller("CarsByRatingCtrl", function($scope, getAllCars){
$scope.update=function(){
    getAllCars.get().success(function(data){
        $scope.carList = data;
        $scope.minReviewNum = 0;

        if ($scope.minReviewNum > 0){
            console.log("passed!")
            for(var i=0;i<$scope.carList.length;i++){
                if ($scope.carList[i]["review"]<$scope.minReviewNum){
                    $scope.carList.splice(i, 1);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
$scope.update();
});
```